# Service that does advanced queries on a data set, and automatically returns relevant updated results every time new data is added to the set?

Tags: sql, database, view, google-cloud-firestore, data-warehouse

I'm looking for a cloud service that can do advanced statistics calculations on a large amount of votes submitted by users, in "real time".

In our app, users can submit different kind of votes like picking a favorite, rating 1-5, say yes/no etc. on various topics.

We also want to show "live" statistics to the user, showing the popularity of a person etc. This will be generated by a rather complex SQL where we are calculating the average number of times a person was picked as favorite, divided by total number of votes and the number of games in which the person has been participating etc. And the score for the latest X games should count higher than the overall score for all games. This is just an example, there are several other SQL queries with similar complexity.

All our presentable data (including calculated statistics) is served from Firestore documents, and the votes will be saved as Firestore documents.

Ideally, the Firebase-backend (functions, firestore etc) should not need to know about the query logic.

What I wish for is a pay as you go cloud service that does the following:

1. I define some schemas and set up the queries we need for the statistics we have (15-20 different SQLs). Like setting up views in MySQL
2. On every vote, we push the vote data to this service, which will store it in a row.
3. The service should then, based on its knowledge about the defined queries, and the content of the pushed vote data, determine which statistics that are affected by the newly added row, and recalculate these. A specific vote type can affect one or more statistics.
4. Every time a statistic is recalculated, the result should be automatically pushed back to our Firebase backend (for instance by calling an HTTPS endpoint that hits a cloud function) - so we can update the relevant Firestore documents.
5. The service should be able to throttle the calculations, like only regenerating new statistics every 1 minute despite having several votes per second on the same topic.

Is there any product like this in the market? Or can it be built by combining available cloud services? And what is the official term for such a product, if I should search for it myself?

I know that I can probably build a solution like this myself, and run it on a cloud hosted database server, which can scale as our need grows - but I believe that I'm not the first developer with a need of this, so I hope that someone has solved it before me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the existing cloud services available on the Google Cloud Platform.
[Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/), [Google Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) (CRON Jobs), [Google Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/)

The services can be used to solve the problems mentioned above:

1) Google BigQuery : Here you can define schema for the data on which you're going to run the SQL queries. BigQuery supports Standard and legacy SQL queries.

2) Every vote can be pushed to the defined BigQuery tables using its streaming insert service.

3) Every vote pushed can trigger the recalculation service which calculates the statistics by executing the defined SQL queries and the query results can be stored as documents in collections in Google Cloud Firestore.

4) Google Cloud Firestore: Here you can store the live statistics of the user. This is a real time database, so you'll be able to configure listeners for the modifications to the statistics and show the modifications as soon as the statistics are recalculated.

5) In the same service which inserts every vote, create a new record with a "syncId" in an another table. The idea is to group a number of votes cast in a particular interval to a its corresponding syncId. The syncId can be suffixed with a timestamp. According to your requirement a particular time interval can be set so that the recalculation can be triggered using CRON jobs service which invokes the recalculation service within the interval. Once the recalculation related to a particular syncId is completed the record corresponding to the syncId should be marked as completed.

We are leveraging the above technologies to build a web application on Google Cloud Platform, where the inputs are recorded on Google Firestore and then stream-inserted to Google BigQuery. The data stored in BigQuery is queried after 30 sec of each update using SQL queries and the query results are stored in Google Cloud Firestore to serve dashboards which are automatically updated using listeners configured for the collection in which the dashboard information is stored.

Comment: Thanks for your response. A few questions:
1) Do you in any way store the SQL queries in BigQuery as views etc?
3) What is this recalculation service? Some cloud function that you wrote yourself?
5) What do you do to process these sync IDs? Do you have a (pseudo) code example?

How do you ensure that data is queried after 30 sec? You have a cron job of * * * * * */30 ? How much do you select in order to determine whether new data has to be processed?

One of my concerns with BigQuery, SlicingDice and other async cloud services is that data is not available immediately after insert.

Comment: 1) SQL query results can be stored as views with expiration time. Views are treated as table resources in BigQuery so we can create a table using the query results and set an expiration time if the view should be discarded later [Creating views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views).

Comment: 3) Recalculation service is basically a [Google Cloud Task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/) with a sync record with a generated sync ID which is created when the first vote is stored. The task can be scheduled to run after 30 sec from its creation time. The task is created and waits 30 sec. So all the votes cast within that 30 sec period should be marked with that sync ID. When the task starts execution, the sync record is marked as "INPROGRESS" and all the new votes are marked with another new sync record. The task executes the desired query and updates the statistics to Cloud Firestore.

Comment: 5) Sync IDs correspond to each recalculation. To ensure that data is queried after 30 s, we use using scheduled tasks in Cloud Tasks where we can set a delay time of 30 s. CRON jobs are an option but during a period where the votes are not cast, the CRON will still run and so it is not preferred. Since the task will be created only when new votes are stored, we will select all the votes by their latest entry in BigQuery table. How much vote to select depends on your logic and the way you design the schema for your BigQuery table.

Comment: In my experience with BigQuery, I was able to insert more than 200 rows of data containing 100+ columns and was able to query the inserted data almost immediately and the data was available 99.999% of the time. Assuming your recalculation is done every 30s or so it will not be a problem. Also BigQuery is charged according to the data queried. So I would totally recommend it for processing huge amount of data.

Comment: Thank you! I think I have an idea of how to build the setup now :)

Just a few more questions:

Comment: 1) I created some views to simplify my queries. But I can see that BQ does not support materialized views, and the queries behind a view is run every time the view is used in a query.
The alternative suggestion is to create a temporary table based on a selection, before doing the actual queries.

So I thought of making a list of all needed queries (based on votes) for a given period (let's say 1 hour) and then before doing the queries, I'd create temporary tables, that I refer to in the queries.

Comment: However, that will probably require the DB to scan all votes and `GROUP BY id` and `COUNT()` them. Let's say there's 1 M votes in the DB and only 100 votes were saved the last hour. Would it then be cheaper to just have a sub-query and JOIN, than to create a new table?

Comment: 2) I was thinking of having a `jobs` collection so for votes affects stats with a 1 hour interval, I'd create a document in `jobs` with a scheduled time of next hour start. And then use the Cloud Task service. 

Then, for every new vote I'd create a doc in `jobs/{jobId}/tasks/{taskId}` and in that doc, I'd have some references to the statistics that I'd need to update. All statistics are saved in firestore documents like `users/{uid}/statistics/votes`.

And when the job is run, I'd simply read all docs in `jobs/{jobId}/tasks` and do the queries and save the results.

Comment: However, I can see that you have the `syncID`s (which which I believe are similar to the `jobID`s i mention) in a BQ table. So I guess that you select all sync IDs when executing the task, and then to the queries? 

What is the advantage of keeping this in BQ, instead of having a scheduled job doc, with a subcollection of the indivitual tasks for that job, as I propose?

Comment: 3) You mention App Engine. What are you using it for, that can't be done in Cloud Functions?

My idea was this:

When a vote is saved in Firestore, trigger a cloud function that inserts it into BQ and then determine based on the vote content, which statistics for which users, that needs update. Find the next scheduled job, and add a reference to the affected statistics to that job.

If no next job, create it and make a Task with a reference to the job ID and a schedule time next 00 minutes

The task should then call an HTTPS cloud function that will do the queries and get data from BQ.

Comment: @EsbenvonBuchwald Hi There! Glad to know that I could be of some help. Here's what I think of the questions. 1) You can create a temporary table when you run the queries for the first time and set the write mode to OVERWRITE so that the data is refreshed on each query. You can also proceed with the sub-query approach. Ultimately it depends upon the amount of data you're expecting and complexity of the sub-query. If there are complex aggregations or user defined functions on a large set of data, it is better to create a table by executing the complex query.

Comment: 2) Yes. `jobId` and `SyncID` are the same. Keeping the `jobId` in BQ offers advantage of using it for joining it with the votes table in BQ for the queries. It is particularly helpful in case you need to execute all the queries related to multiple jobs and join them in a final query. It comes handy if you can mark the votes according to the jobs using the `jobId`. So I recommend saving the `jobId` in Firestore as well as BQ.

Comment: 3) App Engine is better suited to applications, which have numerous pieces of functionality behaving in various inter-related (or even unrelated) ways, while cloud functions are more specifically single-purpose functions that respond to some event and perform some specific action.You could easily replicate Cloud Functions on App Engine, but replicating a large scale App Engine application using a bunch of discrete Cloud Functions would be complicated. Ultimately these both run on similar underlying infrastructure at Google, and it's up to you to decide which one works for the task at hand.